# Jenkins - Performance Report appears twice

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm using Jenkins 1.6.0.7 with Performance plugin

In the left menu of a job, Performance Report appears twice instead of once (with same link)
Is there a reason or it's a bug of Jenkins\plugin?